# How can I create a button with scaling text

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout with cells, populated like this:

```
    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_table);

    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            Button button = new Button(getActivity());
            button.setText("Button");
            button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mainPresenter.processAction(((Button)v).getText().toString());
                }
            });
            buttons.add(button);
            row.addView(button);
        }

        tableLayout.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

This works nicely to start with, however sometimes the buttons have their text set to something that is too large for the allocated width. This results in the button expanding to accommodate the text.

I would like it to work the other way around - the buttons maintain their assigned width, and instead the font that is used shrinks to make sure that the text fits into the button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

when you add the button into a table row, instead of using `buttons.add(button);`, use `buttons.add(button, new TableRow.LayoutParams(100, 100));` which would make the button be 100x100 large.

Comment: I don't want fixed size buttons - I just want the text displayed in them to fit to available size.